# Bootstrap Modal sitting behind backdrop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, z-index

So I'm having nearly the exact same problem as [@Jamescoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991085/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop-in-chrome) was but I think that my issue is coming from the fact that I have already positioned a couple of DIVs to create a sliding nav panel.

Here's my exact setup replicated:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQ8U/2/

*BONUS: Feel free to grab the code for the sliding panel if you'd like :)*

The z-indexes shouldn't conflict and their values would show that they are stacking correctly, but visually they are not.

Once you click the 'Open Modal' button the `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>` covers everything! (you'll have to re-run the code to reset it)

I don't know quite how to remedy this one...Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be the [same issue as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background); see that accepted answer for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: @TobyJ 's provided link has the answer, but not the "accepted" one ;) The answer by Adam Albright is the one that works best, without any complications. That is, if you're using jQuery.

Comment: Check this I've updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQ8U/513/

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Just move the entire modal outside of the rest of your code, to the very bottom. It doesn't need to be nested in any other element, other than the body.

```
<body>
    <!-- All other HTML -->
    <div>
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/ZBQ8U/6/)

They hint at this solution in the documentation.

> **Modal Markup Placement**
>    Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components
>   affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Comment: Thank you! Moving the modal as suggested did the trick perfectly! Everyone, be sure to read below @davidpauljunior's in-depth explanation as to why the `.modal-backdrop` was covering everything up!!

Comment: I wrote my code like this and yet it's still happening. :/

Comment: That was actually the solution to my problem. My div was within the form of Struts.

Comment: @KehlanKrumme this is not the fault of Bootstrap. Understanding "stacking context" is necessary to solve this problem. Good reading: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I could fix it by adding css for the `.modal-backdrop`

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Although this works, form controls still seem to appear above the backdrop, clicking anywhere dismisses the modal, but it doesn't look great.

A better workaround for me is to bind to the shown event (once the page is loaded) and to correct the z-index property.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $(this).css("z-index", parseInt($('.modal-backdrop').css('z-index')) + 1);
});
```

In this case, if you are OK with changing the DOM on modal shown:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  //Make sure the modal and backdrop are siblings (changes the DOM)
  $(this).before($('.modal-backdrop'));
  //Make sure the z-index is higher than the backdrop
  $(this).css("z-index", parseInt($('.modal-backdrop').css('z-index')) + 1);
});
```

Comment: The only solution that worked in my case! Thank you. by the way, the CSS part was enough for me

Comment: z-index: -1; made some page elements to overlay the backdrop. $(this).before($('.modal-backdrop')); worked better, but when you scroll down, the page elements start to appear. The solution was to move the modal window out of the body. See my reply.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! :) The third code block snippet is what worked for me :)

Answer (score 30):

Although the z-index of the `.modal` is higher than that of the `.modal-backdrop`, that `.modal` is in a parent div `#content-wrap` which has a lower z-index than `.modal-backdrop` (z-index: 1002 vs z-index: 1030).

Because the parent has lower z-index than the `.modal-backdrop` everything in it will be behind the modal, irrespective of any z-index given to the children.

If you remove the `z-index` you have set on both the `body div#fullContainer #content-wrap` and also on the `#ctrlNavPanel`, everything seems to work ok.

```
body div#fullContainer #content-wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 8px #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#ctrlNavPanel {
  background: #333333;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
}
```

NOTE:  I think that you may have initially used z-indexes on the #content-wrap and #ctrlNavPanel to ensure the nav sits behind, but that's not necessary because the nav element comes before the content-wrap in the HTML, so you only need to position them, not explicitly set a stacking order.

---

**EDIT**
As Schmalzy picked up on, the links are no longer clickable.  This is because the full-container is 100% wide and so covers the navigation.  The quickest way to fix this is to place the navigation inside that div:

```
<div id="fullContainer">
  <aside id="ctrlNavPanel">
    <ul class="nav-link-list">
      <li><label>Menu</label></li>
      <li><a href="/"><span class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></span> Home</a></li>
      <li><a><span class="fa fa-lg fa-group"></span>About Us</a></li>
      <li><a><span class="fa fa-lg fa-book"></span> Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ZBQ8U/7/)

Comment: Can whoever downvoted provide an explanation as to why this is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, I was getting to that.. Removing the z-index seems to break his `#ctrlNavPanel`. Links no longer work.

Comment: Ah yes well spotted!  Have added in an HTML edit fix for that.  Thanks

Comment: @davidpauljunior Great in-depth explanation! Thank you so much for the quick response!! This will be very helpful for others struggling with z-indexing as I was with in this scenario.  I've gotta give the nod to @Schmalzy though for catching the `#ctrlNavPanel` break and the simplicity of suggesting to just move the modal to the bottom of the code just before the closing body tag `</body>`.

Answer (score 17):

None of the answers worked well enough for me.
The problem appeared to lie where the modal windows needs to be outside of the body.and it is not best

So this code done the job just prefectly:

```html
$('.modal ').insertAfter($('body'));
```

```
$('#product_' + product_id + ' .modal ').insertAfter($('body'));
```

Comment: Same for me. The solutions with the index worked only "haflish". There where still elements hidden behind the backdrop. This solution with moving the modal outside the body worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This makes inputs in the modal not working on IE11 (and maybe other versions). DO NOT USE this solution, if you have inputs inside modal.

Answer (score 16):

I'm wary of moving the modal content outside its original context: other JS or styles might depend on that context.

However, I doubt there are any scripts or styles that require a specific context for the backdrop.

So my solution is to move the backdrop adjacent to the modal content, forcing it into the same stacking context:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $('.modal-backdrop').before($(this));
});
```

It's only a slight deviation from [jacoswarts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1656059/jacoswarts)' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28825768/684776), so thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: Thanks for that man, you saved me a lot of time! I was already searching this for a couple of hours...

Comment: @Scissors38th I remember this issue like it was yesterday. Glad to help! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Try remove the backdrop, if you don't realy need it `(data-backdrop= "false"):`

```
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="false" role="dialog" id="my-modal" aria-labelledby="modal-title">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">No Backdrop</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        Look! No backdrop here!
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I know it is late, I encountered the same problem but I had to hack it out as below;

```
 .modal-backdrop {
      /* bug fix - no overlay */    
      display: none;    
}

.modal{
    /* bug fix - custom overlay */   
    background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.45);
}
```

Comment: Works great, fixed my issue

Answer (score 5):

I was fighting with the same problem some days... I found three posible solutions, but i dont know, which is the most optimal, if somebody tell me, i will be grateful.

the modifications will be in bootstrap.css

Option 1:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040; <- DELETE THIS LINE
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Option 2:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1; <- MODIFY THIS VALUE BY -1
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Option 3:

```
/*ADD THIS*/
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I used the option 2.

Comment: z-index: 1; worked for me

Answer (score 4):

In my case one of parents of my modal was animated and had this

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

The blocker here is `animation-fill-mode: both;`. I could not just move modal outside, so the solution was to override 'animation-fill-mode' to `animation-fill-mode: none;`. Animation still worked fine.

Comment: This is answer is seriously overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

If you use JQuery, you can use the appendTo() to append the modal to a specific element, in this case, the , in most case, a simple one line can move your modal on top of the backdrop regardless where your modal div's position

```
$("#myModal").appendTo("body");
```

here's the reference of the JQuery appendTo function:
http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

I updated it to your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZBQ8U/240/

Comment: this is just amazing, I tried insertafter body but I had styling issues in the modal however, I used $('.modal').appendTo($('body')); and it worked

Answer (score 2):

The problem persists if any ancestor of the [.modal] element has CSS property `z-index` set.
The [.modal] element inherits the CSS `z-index` from that container element.
While the [.modal-backdrop] is inserted into the [body] element dynamically from `jQuery` code, which has default `z-index: 1040` from `bootstrap.css`.

I came out with two way CSS solution, is better than changing any other behavior of the default event and element.

1. Set the `z-index: 1041` or higher value for the parent element of the [.modal], that ancestor element is causing the [.modal] is underneath the [.modal-backdrop].

Or

2. Set the `z-index: 1039` or lower value for the [.modal-backdrop] in CSS file, if available. Because the HTML [.modal-backdrop] is not available in your code.

[Note: the CSS `z-index` property may require using `!important` flag]

[Note: default `z-index: 1040` for [.modal-backdrop] is completely depended on `bootstrap.css`]

Answer (score 1):

Another resolution for this problem is to add `z-index: 0;` to .modal-backdrop class in your bootstrap-dialog.css file if you don't want to modify bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 1):

if we cannot delete backdrop and/or we have component framework such angular or vue we cannot move modal to the root. i did this trick: put my custom modal-backdrop container(with aditional class) as sibling for modal-dialog  container and added some css

```
<div bsModal #moneyModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <!-- magic container-->
    <div class="modal-holder modal-backdrop" (click)="moneyModal.hide()"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.modal-backdrop{z-index: -1}// or you can disable modal-backdrop
.modal-holder.modal-backdrop{z-index: 100}
.modal-holder + .modal-dialog {z-index: 1000}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this :

```
<div
  class="modal fade stick-up disable-scroll"
  id="filtersModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="filtersModal"
  aria-hidden="false"
  style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);" data-backdrop="false"
>
....
</div>

Adding style="" and data-backdrop false would fix it.
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using **ASP.NET MVC**,

Needing to move the modal div just before the `</body>` tag but can't do it because you are using a **Layout** page

Define a section in you `_Layout.cshtml` file just before the body tag, eg:

```
... some html in layout page ...
@RenderSection("bottomHTML", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your view

```
@section bottomHTML 
{
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalID" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="demo-default-modal" aria-hidden="true">
... rest of the modal div HTML ...
}
```

This way, the modal HTML will be rendered before the body tag and the modal now should be displayed correctly..

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **backdrop**, insert this code in your css file

```
.modal-backdrop {
      /* bug fix - no overlay */    
      display: none;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `z-index: 1040`;

from this file `bootstrap.css` class `.modal-backdrop`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the follow html

`<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">`

added it and worked without problems

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the chance to move the modal markup since i added it in a partial template within a conditional what worked for me is add CSS bellow

```
.modal.fade {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, when boostrap add class "in" through js apply display: block and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Found that applying ionic framework (ionic.min.cs) after bootstrap coursing this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put the modal to the root (if your use angular and the modal is in a controller for example), **modifying** bootstrap or using **js** is obviously a **bad** solution.

so saying you have your website structure:

```
//not working
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <modal></modal>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

open your code inspector and move the modal to the root, it should be working (but no where you want):

```
//should be working
<div>
    <div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<modal></modal>
```

now put it in the first div and check if it's working: if yes check the next child until it's not working and find the div that is the problem;

```
//should be working
<div>
    <div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <modal></modal>
</div>
```

Once you know which div is the problem you can play with the css display and position to make it work.

everyone has a different structure but in my case setting a parent to `display: table;` was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Put this code wherever you want

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var max_index = null;
    $('.modal.fade.in').not($(this)).each(function (index , value){
        if(max_index< parseInt( $(this).css("z-index")))
            max_index = parseInt( $(this).css("z-index"));
    });
    if (max_index != null) $(this).css("z-index", max_index + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many times , you cannot move the modal outside as this affects your design structure.

The reason the backdrop comes above your modal is id the parent has any position set.

A very simple way to solve the problem other then moving your modal outside is move the backdrop inside structure were you have your modal. In your case, it could be

```
$(".modal-backdrop").appendTo("main");
```

Note that this solution is applicable if you have a definite strucure for your application and you cant just move the modal outside as it will go against the design structure

Answer (score 0):

just move your modal outside of all div contents, place it mostly prior to closing of body.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem  that the fade was not working and the overlay stayed on the page.
I had dynamic content added back to the page (refresh on some content only on modal action).
I also had this $('#rejectModal-'+itemId).modal('hide') (itemId is dynamic id for multiple modals in a single page for rejecting some information) but the problem was still not gone.

The overlay was staying because my layout was not set to null in the partial view
After setting this the problem was gone:

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the modal is not in any parent div.
Then add 
$('#myModal').appendTo("body")

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to all answers here, i found out, that the bootstrap4 "animated fadeIn" is also causing this error (not clickable modal behind background):

check if your modal is in the following parent tag (bootstrap animation)

`<div class="animated fadeIn"></div>`

I removed this tag - solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDecision" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Height="30px">Please select recovery delivery option</asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEmail" CssClass="submit btn btn-primary" Width="100px" runat="server"
                OnClick="ModalRecovery">Email</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnText" CssClass="submit btn btn-primary" Width="100px" runat="server"
                OnClick="ModalRecovery">Text</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var element = $('#modalDecision');
    // also taken from bootstrap 3 docs
    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // keep in mind this only works as long as Bootstrap only supports 1 modal at a time, which is the case in Bootstrap 3 so far...
        var backDrop = $("<div class='modal-backdrop' style='z-index:-1;opacity:.5'></div>");
        $(element).append($(backDrop));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i encountred this problem, and after investigating my css, the main container (direct child of the body) had:

```
position: relative
z-index: 1
```

the backdrop worked well after i removed those two properties. You may also encounter this problem if the main wraper have a `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

if you have nested modals this is the clue :

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css("z-index", parseInt($('.modal-backdrop').css('z-index')) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For situations regarding frameworks that don't permit you to just move html/css around.

append the modal to the end of the body like

```
$("#EditModal").modal("show");
$("#EditModal").appendTo("body");
```

and destroy with

```
$("#EditModal").remove();
```

more at:  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/14/bootstrap-modal-dialog-showing-under-modal-background

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case the *bootstrap 5* `modal-backdrop` was getting the precedence over the modal itself because my modal `div` contained the CSS as `z-index; auto`. Which is where the `modal-backdrop` was taking precedence over the modal itself.