# Bootstrap Modal Popup Not Clickable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) to add a modal popup. Upon clicking the trigger button, the modal is dark and unclickable. Any idea what's causing this or where to look?

[image]

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require miracle/jquery.noconflict
//= require miracle/modernizr.2.8.3.min
//= require miracle/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min
//= require miracle/jquery-ui.1.11.2.min
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min
//= require miracle/jquery.stellar.min
//= require miracle/waypoints.min
//= require owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min
//= require jquery.sky.carousel/jquery.sky.carousel-1.0.2
//= require miracle/jquery.plugins
//= require miracle/main
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: You need to post the rest of your code/output (HTML/CSS/JS), as the modal itself works fine. This is most likely due to where the modal has been placed.

Comment: I've tried placing the code in various places and the result is the same. I suspect this could be caused by a jquery conflict?

Comment: Well, you also have Magnific included, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's a CSS conflict happening. Basically, the z - index of the modal looks to be wrong.

Comment: @vanburen you pointed me in the right direction. Looks like I just had to move the modal to the very bottom of the html right before `</body>` and leave the trigger button where it is. This also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop/20983718#20983718

Comment: Sounds good and glad I could help.

Comment: Can you give me a jsfiddle url or live demo?

Comment: I too had this problem, put the modal at bottom of html to fix the prob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes, changing the z-index can mess up things with Bootstrap so as they say in [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), try to place your `<!-- Modal -->` block on top of your page. 
If it's a modal that is accessible from many places in your app you can place it in a partial and call it on top of your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` like so (sorry, it's a slim template, tell me if you need erb translation):

```
doctype html
html
  head
    == render 'layouts/meta'

    = stylesheet_link_tag …
    = javascript_include_tag …
    = csrf_meta_tags

  body

    == render 'path/to/your/modal'

    .container
      == yield

    == render 'layouts/footer'
```

Otherwise, you could try to do a special `<%== yield :modal %>` in your `application.html.erb` and call it from somewhere else with `<%- content_for :modal %>. Not sure about the erb syntax here.
It's explained here : [Using The Content For Method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)

Comment: I currently have the model in the application.html.erb, but I'm not sure how to pass a variable from the view (that's calling the model) to the model itself. Currently trying to use javascript, but is there a better approach?

Comment: This means you must use the second technique. The first one would only work if you were calling an instance variable such as `@something` created by ApplicationController. Something you need to access from anywhere in your app. For the second technique, in your `application.html.erb`, instead of placing your modal directly (or by rendering a partial), place a `<%= yield :modal %>`. Then, in your view, inside a `<%- content for :modal %>` block, you can place your modal or render a partial. This will place your modal on top of the rest.

Comment: placing <!-- Modal --> block on top of your page, works for me.

Answer (score 45):

i solved the same problem when i add data-backdrop="false" in my modal like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="userGoing" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false">
```

Comment: it worked for me thank you. do you know the reason, to happen this?

Comment: You have no idea how much this helped me! Thank - I added  `data-backdrop="false"` and all is well.

Answer (score 4):

Add the below code in the same page.

```
#myModal{
 z-index: 9999
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.modal-dialog` has `pointer-events` set to `none`.

I overwrote that property and set `pointer-events: unset;`

so:

```
.modal-dialog {
  pointer-events: unset !important;
}
```

This did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

After long time, i got this simple error just by

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I call a modal from another modal (but not when I call only the first one).

So, this might not help **you** but it can save someone else a lot of time: I had a different definition of fade effects and there was the line with `display: inline-block`. I removed it and the problem's gone.

The failing CSS definition:

```
.fade {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```