# bootstrap modal show with black disabled background

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal like:

```
<div class="modal show" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>My Modal Body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It shows me the model at start but what I want is the background to be black.. or say like transparent when this modal appears and the background should be disabled ..

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Modal sitting behind backdrop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the class `modal show` you can manually add `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>`, so the resulting code looks like:

```
<div class="modal show" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>My Modal Body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

If you use `modal fade` as class, the `modal-backdrop` should appear automatically.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/dvv6dvug/