# Bootstrap Modal Pup Up on Sidebar sitting behind backdrop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, sidebar

Bootstrap's modal pop up has been appearing behind the background. Tried applying:

- [Bootstrap Modal sitting behind backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop)

and seem not to work. Im thinking, maybe its because its inside a sidebar. The contents of the rest of the page is called via include(). And the modal seemed to be applying on the include() layer.

```
<div class="nav nav-sidebar">
<input type='button' value='SURVEY!' class='btn btn-md btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal'>
<!--Your Modal Body Here -->
<div class='modal fade' id='modal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
          <!--Your Modal Close Button-->
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
          <!--Your Modal Title-->
        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Please Confirm Action</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <!--Your Modal content here-->
        <p>Are you sure you want to proceed with your action ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
       <a href='home.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes I Do</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: On click button SURVEY! on sidebar]
I want it to work in the front layer as to how it should be. Any work around for this?

**EDIT**
Sidebar Class

```
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 22px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}
```

Comment: Update with the sidebar class

Answer (score 1):

@Dexter: in the [Bootstrap Modal sitting behind backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop) have already mention about "move the entire modal outside of the rest of your code, to the very bottom". Have you tried as following code?

```
<body>
    <div class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <input type='button' value='SURVEY!' class='btn btn-md btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal'>

    </div>

    <!--Your Modal Body Here -->
    <div class='modal fade' id='modal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
      <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
              <!--Your Modal Close Button-->
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
              <!--Your Modal Title-->
            <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Please Confirm Action</h4>
          </div>
          <div class='modal-body'>
            <!--Your Modal content here-->
            <p>Are you sure you want to proceed with your action ?</p>
          </div>
          <div class='modal-footer'>
           <a href='home.php'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes I Do</button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The page only contains the sidebar and the nav bar. the rest is just included with `include()` . So I think it's not the workaround I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, can try set .modal-content {z-index: 9999999}; in css code to see what happen ?

Comment: Seemed that z-index is not applicable to `.modal-content` buy yes, im getting where you're going at. I need the same concept. Appreciate it trungk18!

Comment: So now the content is located above backdrop already is this? Not sure why but probably we need to follow the html structure from Bootstrap to get what we want :)

Comment: My parent container is `<div class="col-md-2 sidebar">` and tried just removing the `sidebar` class and it works perfectly fine but removes the benefits of the class.

Comment: Can you bring up the css style of sidebar here and we can take a look ?