# Modal cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I implement a bootstrap modal in the application I made. I don't exactly what is happening to this. After I implemented some js functions and etc. the page is cannot be clicked.

[image: Click here to view the image]

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The image seems to work fine ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop

Comment: My code works, however, when the modal pops up, it cannot be clicked anymore. Please see attached image if possible.

Comment: @Crashtor, I cannot put it outside of some divs because I am passing some id to it..

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountering is about of div having an absolute position with lesser z-index. So what I did is that I changed the z-index to higher value. Like this:  style="width:250%;position:absolute;z-index:9999;margin-top:400px;"

Comment: The probable reason your question has  been downvoted is not only due to lack of research, code examples etc, but primarily due to the fact that there are already literarily 100's of questions on SO that already answers your question. A simple search will without a doubt help you get this fixed. As a new member of SO, I can understand your frustration, but SO is not a place you should resort to because of laziness. I encourage you to help make SO a great environment for new and experienced programmers alike by trying to be **helpful/useful** in both **answers and question**.

Comment: That would be right. But I am a little bit dismayed. First thing, they must give some links accordingly like what you did. Anyways, I solved it already. They don't deserve a respect. Thank you @Crashtor!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `$event.stopPropagation()` on your model.

When you pass event to open modal you have to put `$event.stopPropagation()` on your model so that it can allow actions on modal.

I hope it will work.