# <div class="modal-backdrop fade"></div> taking entire window space

Tags: bootstrap-4

The HTML of my Angular application has a modal box which pops on application start up.

```
<div >
  <div class="css-grid-container" *ngIf="!loading">
    <app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
    <app-content-component></app-content-component>

    <app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
  </div>
  <app-progress-bar></app-progress-bar>

  <app-dialog-box #dialogBox [dialogMessage]="" [dialogID]="'appDialog'" [dialogContext]=""></app-dialog-box>
</div>
```

`app-dialog-box` is an Angular component and it shows/hides Bootstrap's modal using JavaScript API `modal('show')` and `modal('hide')`.

```
<div #modal class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id={{dialogID}}>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">CodingJedi</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="dialogHide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{dialogMessage}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="dialogHide()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code to show and hide the modal

```
 $(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('show');
```

and

```
$(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('hide');
```

My issue is that Bootstrap seem to add `<div class="modal-backdrop fade"></div>` in the html which takes up the entire page and makes other components unclickable. See the pic below. You'll notice that the `div` takes the entire space even when the modal is not visible because after clicking `close` on the modal, it is hidden using `$(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('hide');`

[image]

It is interesting to notice that the modal div is within the `app-dialog` element but the modal background div is not at the same level! (see pic 2)
What could I do to solve my issue?

[image]

UPDATE

Still not able to find the answer but the issue certainly seems to be with `z-index` value. The modal box is created within the `app-dialog-box` within app-root

```
<app-root>
<div>
  <!-- the below div is a grid container - parent. All elements one element below this are its children.
  Elements under children are not grid children -->
  <div class="css-grid-container" *ngIf="!loading">
    <app-nav-component></app-nav-component><!-- grid child -->
    <!--this component has router-outlet to put new componnents in it -->
    <!-- the components which target this router-outlet could be containers-->
    <app-content-component></app-content-component><!-- grid child -->

    <app-footer-component></app-footer-component><!-- grid child -->

  <app-progress-bar></app-progress-bar><!-- not a grid child -->  <!--this is positioned using absolute positioning and thus will not affect positions of others -->
  <app-dialog-box #dialogBox [dialogMessage]="" [dialogID]="'appDialog'" [dialogContext]=""></app-dialog-box>
  </div>
</div>
<app-root>
```

But `Bootstrap` adds the `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>` at the same level as `app-root` and not inside `app-root`. As `app-root`'s z-index is lower than that of `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>`, the backdrop is always on top. As explained in [Bootstrap Modal sitting behind backdrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop)

"
Although the z-index of the .modal is higher than that of the .modal-backdrop, if .modal is in a parent div, z-index will not take priority and .modal-backdrop will have higher z-index`. This is because if the parent has lower z-index than the .modal-backdrop, everything in it will be behind the modal, irrespective of any z-index given to the children."

Comment: set z-index to 10000 or above and check if the problem is still there

Comment: thanks but it doesn't :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519660/twitter-bootstrap-modal-backdrop-doesnt-disappear

Comment: Thanks @SunSul. The link has several suggestions but it isn't clear which one is genuine and which is a hack! I would rather prefer an explanation why the problem exists as this seem to be very basic functionality of modals.

Comment: @SubSul - it seems the solution described in the link you provided is my best option for the moment! I'll research a bit more though

Comment: @Satya - my temporary solution is based on your suggestion as well. On close of the dialog box, the component emits an event and when I handle that event, I set the following properties in the top most div (id = top-div)     `$('#top-div').css('z-index',10000);
    $('#top-div').css('width','100%');
    $('#top-div').css('position','absolute');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was something entirely different! I had added the logic to show the `modal` in `ngAfterViewChecked`. This function gets called repeatedly by Angular (see Lifecycle hook in Angular). It seems that due to repeated execution of this function, `Bootstrap` was adding multiple `` but was removing only one leaving another one to cover the page. I moved the logic to `ngAfterViewInit` which is called once and it solved my issue.

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){}

  {

    setTimeout(()=>this.isSignupProcess()); //moved this to ngViewInit

  }
```

See [Getting different behaviour of bootstrap for almost identical html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353614/getting-different-behaviour-of-bootstrap-for-almost-identical-html). I created another problem, it has a video which explains the behaviour.

The way I debugged it was interesting. I added few `console.log` in `bootstrap.js` and observed that the messages I had added were being printed repeatedly.